# How to extract last file added to an zip archive

Tags: linux, archive, unzip

I have a monthly archive, that each day a new file is added to the archive.  Occasionally I have to extract the last file added.  The file name are random so I do not know what the file name is.  I use this process.

Step 1
unzip -l /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip
gives me list of files in archive and I write down last one added ie. latest_file.dat

Step 2
unzip /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip  latest_file.dat
I then extract that file from the archive.

what I would like to do is do this in one command, basically I want to extract the last file added to an archive in one command on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unzip /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip $(unzip -l /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip | sort -k2 | tail -5 | head -1 | awk '{ print $4 }')
```

$() expands the first command and uses the expansion in the second. We list the archive entries in date order and use tail, head and sort to get the line required. We then use awk to print out the file path (the 4th space delimited field)

Alternatively, this can be done with the awk system function to action the unzip.

```
 unzip -l /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip | sort -k2 | tail -5 | head -1 | awk '{ system("unzip /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip "$4) }'
```

Comment: Trying this I ran this command
`unzip -l /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip | sort -k2 | tail -5 | head -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'`
and it did return the proper file name.  However when I ran the whole command
`unzip /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip $(unzip -l /path/to/archive/dec2020.zip | sort -k2 | tail -5 | head -1 | awk '{ print $4 }')`
It extracted all files in archive.

Comment: Sorry trying to figure out how to comment.

Comment: Are you using a bash shell?

Comment: Ok. Try the alternative I just posted.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks a bunch Raman.  and you taught me some stuff as well so a good day.

Comment: One more question why tail -5 and not tail -1 as i'm only concerned about the last file.  and if tail -1 returns the file why head -1

Comment: This was down to the output from unzip -1. The bottom four lines contain a summary and the directory itself. It is the fifth from bottom line that contains the last directory.

Comment: Answered question.  unzip -l returns some extra stuff at the end.  I had to change to -4 though

Comment: No worries. Happy to help